# CSS3 arrow box like branch.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

I really like the arrowboxes on branch.com, example: http://tinyurl.com/lw5zlhu

How does one create arrowboxes with a timeline like branch.com?

I have done this so fare: http://jsfiddle.net/uFPEf/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
       Curabitur adipiscing dignissim purus at adipiscing.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
       Curabitur adipiscing dignissim purus at adipiscing.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
       Curabitur adipiscing dignissim purus at adipiscing.
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", 
    "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", 
    sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
    padding:20px;
}
.item{ 
    border-radius:3px; 
    padding:10px; 
    border: solid 1px #EEEEEE; 
}
.item p {
    color:#333333;
    padding:20px;
}

.timeline { 
    width: 100%;
}

.line {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Well, they use images

Comment: I know they use images, but this is still possible with css3

Comment: Yup, I'll have it for ya in a jiff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS' before and after elements. If you target directly where you want with absolute positioning, and give a white background, you can emulate it.

```
.item:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    content: '';
}
.item:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    content: '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uFPEf/7/

Comment: Nice, but what if you want one with only one arrow in the bottom, and the rest with two arrows top and bottom like you have now. can you please provide that? Do you which browsers this would work in?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but why not try it yourself? I've given you a basic model to work with. If you're coding a website, this should give you a basic understanding of how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, you right. But do you know which browsers support this? =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS solution
it may be better to use a image though.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#EEE;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #999;
    margin:50px;
    position:relative; /* This makes sure the ::after is absolute to this element */
}

#box:after{
    content:''; /* Content is required on all ::before & ::after */
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #C2C1C1; /* 3D'ish effect */
    border-left:1px solid #C2C1C1;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-12px;  /* Half the height of the square */
    left:15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* rotate 45deg to fake a triangle */
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3XHH/)